# Win10 guests high KVM host CPU usage

Tags: debian, windows, kvm, qemu, libvirt

Some time ago it was noticed that Win10 1803 WM's would give high CPU usage on the host e.g. 25%, even though client CPU usage 0%.
It was solved by having these settings in your virt XML file:

```
 <hyperv>
   <relaxed state='on'/>
   <vapic state='on'/>
   <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
   <synic state='on'/> 
   <stimer state='on'/>
 </hyperv>

 <clock offset='localtime'>
   <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
   <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
   <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
   <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
 </clock>
```

But the problem is new back.
I've moved from Debian stretch (`QEMU 2.8.1` / `Kernel 4.9`) to Buster (`QEMU 3.1.0` / `Kernel 4.19`) and Windows 10 1809.
The problem might be related to I can no longer use `<synic state='on'/>` on Buster which I could on Stretch on the same hardware.
When I try to start the VM i get this error

```
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: Hyper-V SynIC (requested by 'hv-synic' cpu flag) requires Hyper-V VP_INDEX ('hv-vpindex')
2019-08-06T13:29:14.114943Z qemu-system-x86_64: kvm_init_vcpu failed: Function not implemented
```

When I run `lscpu` I don't have any `hv*` flags at all. But again, it worked on Stretch on the same CPU.

Comment: Compated the XML with an old VM which support the `<synic state='on'/>`. The difference is `machine='pc-i440fx-2.8'` and `machine='pc-q35-3.1'`....need to do some more investigation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least on `QEMU 3.1.0` / `Kernel 4.19` it seems QEMU machine types > **pc-i440fx-3.0** doesn't support synIC, which is needed on Windows 10 guest build  >= 1803 to not have issues with high host CPU usage.

I've tested following machine types:
**pc-i440fx-2.8** (OK)
**pc-i440fx-3.0** (OK)
**pc-i440fx-3.1** (Fail)
**pc-q35-3.1** (Fail)

The XML element in the Virt XML file:

```
</features>
   ...
   <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
      <synic state='on'/>
      <stimer state='on'/>
   </hyperv>
   ...
</features>

<clock offset='localtime'>
   <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
   <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
   <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
   <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
</clock>
```

**UPDATE:**
It turned out to be my XML settings that was the issue!
The following will also make your new QEMU machine types run smoothly without high host CPU usage:

```
<hyperv>
   <relaxed state='on'/>
   <vpindex state='on'/>
   <synic state='on'/>
   <stimer state='on'/>
</hyperv>

<clock offset='localtime'>
   <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
   <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
   <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
   <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
</clock>
```

A big thank you to [Vitaly Kuznetsov](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1738244#c6) for being so patient with me and made me realize the misconfiguration.

Comment: Thank you for the above share - it was a massive improvement to some similar problems I was experiencing.

Comment: this is also working for machine: `<type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-rhel7.6.0">hvm</type>`.